# Global Maxima of a function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, exponential-function, maxima-minima

Let $x=e^{-3t}(3 \cos(4t)+\frac{9}{4} \sin(4t)), t\geq 0$. Prove that $\lvert x \rvert \leq 3$.

Now, using a graphical approach, the above result is clear. However, is there a way to prove the above upper bound using algebraic methods? I tried doing the obvious, like finding the first derivative, but this method is not sufficient since it only proves that $t=0$ yields a $\textbf{local maximum}$, and this function is not monotone decreasing over the given interval.

Comment: changed; thanks for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 1):

Note here that you're dealing with the magnitude of $x.$ Thus since the exponential is always decreasing and the sinusoid is always $\le 1$ in magnitude, then the global maximum is the first maximum value achieved.

Comment: But how does one make it formal in the context of this question?

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI Re write the function as $$\frac{15}{4}e^{-3t}\sin(4t+\phi),$$ where $\tan\phi=3/4.$ Then the absolute maximum occurs in $[0,+\infty)$ at the first point where the function attains a local maximum, or else at the boundary, since we have that $$|x|=\frac{15}{4}e^{-3t}|\sin(4t+\phi)|\le \frac{15}{4}e^{-3t},$$ which decreases monotonically. Indeed the maximum value occurs at the boundary, namely $15/4,$ since we have that $-3t\le 0\implies e^{-3t}\le 1$ for $t\ge 0.$ Thus, the maximum occurs where $e^{-3t}$ is absolutely maximum, provided the sinusoid is also maximum here, which is.

Comment: But clearly, when $t=0$, we have $x=3$.

Comment: So we actually have a better upper bound.

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI When $t=0,$ then we have that $\sin\phi=12/15,$ so that the value of the function at the beginning is $3,$ as before.

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI Sorry here. I see a little mistake that might have caused confusion -- $\tan\phi$ should be $4/3,$ not $3/4.$

Comment: would you want to write your comments into a new answer? Then I can accept and reward you the points.

Comment: Also, is there a more formal way to show that the global maximum is attained at either the local maximum or the boundary? Or is this intuitive enough to be taken as true?

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI There is a theorem that any continuous function on an interval of the form $[a,b]$ attains its maximum and minimum on this interval. For your function, since the magnitude is decreasing, then in every interval of the form $[0,t]$ there is a maximum and minimum value. Now since this is falling off, then the first maximum is the global maximum. This is obtained either when $t=0$ or for some $t>0.$

Comment: @ONGSEEHAIHCI As for another answer, is that really necessary? What of I add a summary of our discussion in the comments, as an edit?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x(0)=3+9/4>3$ so the statement is not accurate. But since $e^{-t}$ decreases faster than any polynomial, let alone a bounded function, then there exists $T>0$ such that $|x(t)|<1$ for all $t>T$.

Comment: thanks, there was a typo; will fix it first

Answer (score 0):

$$x(t)=e^{-3t}[3 \cos 4t-9\frac{\sin (4t)}{4}, t\ge 0$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}==\frac{75}{4}e^{-3t} \sin (4t), `~x''(t)=-\frac{75}{4}e^{-3t}[4 \cos 4z-3 \sin 4z]$$ When $4t=n\pi, n=0,1,2,3..$ there will be max of min. As $x''(0)<0$ there will be a max at $x=0$. Due to exponential fall-off of $x(t)$ other max/min will be of lesser absolute height. So $$x(t) \le x(0)=3.$$
Next at $t=\pi/4$ there will be the first min as $x'(\pi/4)=0, x''(\pi/4)=75e^{-3\pi/4}$ and $x_{min}=x(\pi/4)=-3 \le 3e^{-3\pi/4}$
So, $x(t)$ will lie between these the first max and the first min, i.r.
$$-3e^{=3\pi/4} \le x(t) \le 3 \implies |x(t)|\le 3.$$

One may also write $$x(t)=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4} e^{-3t} \sin [4t+\tan^{-1}(4/3)] \implies |x(t)|=\frac{15}{4} e^{-3t} |\sin [4t+\tan^{-1}(4/3)]$ \implies x(0)=\frac{15}{4}e^{-3t} \sin (\tan^{-1}(4/3)=3.$$
Therefore $$|x(t)| \le 3$$

Comment: But the problem is $x(t)$ itself can take on negative values. Thus, $x(t) \leq 3$ does not imply  $\lvert x(t) \rvert \leq 3$.

Comment: @ONG SEE Yes you are right. I hane now added some more argument, You may please see now.

Comment: Is there a more rigorous proof that other maximum and minimum points respectively will be of lesser amplitude?

Comment: @ONG SEE I have edited it more you may see.